# metrics on Spark jobs only show basic high level info, Spark 1.3

Tags: apache-spark

I have been looking up getting Spark metrics to work following the example here
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/monitoring.html

Have a Cloudera CDH 5.4 VM with Spark 1.3

So after I kick off a Spark job, I can see something like the following

```
.../metrics/json/
```

> {"version":"3.0.0","gauges":{"app-20151203090431-0003..BlockManager.disk.diskSpaceUsed_MB":{"value":0},"app-20151203090431-0003..BlockManager.memory.maxMem_MB":{"value":2385},"app-20151203090431-0003..BlockManager.memory.memUsed_MB":{"value":0},"app-20151203090431-0003..BlockManager.memory.remainingMem_MB":{"value":2385},"app-20151203090431-0003..DAGScheduler.job.activeJobs":{"value":1},"app-20151203090431-0003..DAGScheduler.job.allJobs":{"value":1},"app-20151203090431-0003..DAGScheduler.stage.failedStages":{"value":0},"app-20151203090431-0003..DAGScheduler.stage.runningStages":{"value":1},"app-20151203090431-0003..DAGScheduler.stage.waitingStages":{"value":0}},"counters":{},"histograms":{},"meters":{},"timers":{}}

But I was more interested in seeing job specific metrics, none of these URL return anything

```
.../metrics/master/json/
.../metrics/worker/json/
.../metrics/applications/json/
```

I understand that with Spark 1.4 there is a RESTFUL API with more info.  Is `Spark 1.3` users then limited to the very basic info available 
via `metrics/json/` ?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the versions, the `../metrics` endpoint simply exposes the values in the [`MetricRegistry`](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/apidocs/com/codahale/metrics/MetricRegistry.html) object, which is an in-memory collection of global metrics which are not collected per job/stage/task... So there is no API to get these metrics per entity.

The [RESTFUL API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) added in version 1.4 is completely separate from this Metric Servlet (which would remain global), but you might be able to find what you need using that RESTFUL API.